# How to activate a new session in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, session

Well, today i kill a session in oracle sql developer, because that session doesn't allow me alter a temporary table, so i investigate in internet what i need to do, and i found a "solution" that i can kill the session that is using the table that i want to modify.

So i kill the session with this command:

ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ',

And it solves that, but the problem happen when i upload my website application again to the server , and i try to execute my application, i got this error:

```
ORA-01012: not logged on
Process ID: 13082
Session ID: 48 Serial number: 58026
```

So, i can't use the database in the server because i killed that session, but if i'm run the application in my computer it works fine.

What can i do to resolve this problem?..

Comment: I'm guessing you need to restart your application server to reconnect to the database. What kind of website application are you running, and what kind of application server are you using? Java EE, python, ruby, ??

Comment: You can’t activate a session in your web app from SQL Developer. The app will have to reconnect. It sounds like it isn’t using a connection pool, as that would normally be automatic. If there is no mechanism in the app/server to reconnect on error or on demand, sounds like you will have to completely stop and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the component in the application which connects to the DB , like the ADO/OLE DB connection code in case the application is .NET - Once that code runs the connection would be restored and the application should be able to create new sessions. This is very specific to where your code connects to the server and without running that piece you cant reconnect to the DB.